# How to sum the attributes from all children in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a recursive DOM tree that looks like

```
<li data-count="3">
  <li data-count="3">
    <li data-count="3">
      <li data-count="2">
      </li>
      <li data-count="1">
      </li>
    </li>
  </li>
</li>
```

This DOM tree is not given as is. Initially, I only have the data-count at the "leave" `<li>` element. The parents of them didn't have that attribute. I want to add them to each level of parents.

I already figured out the traversal algorithm for this, shown below:

```
function count(node) {
  if (!node.hasClass('leaf')) {
    node.children('li').each(function() {
      count($(this));
    }
    node.attr("data-count") = sum(node.children('li').attr("data-count"));
  }
}
```

However, I am not so familiar with javascript or jquery so I am stuck at this syntax:

```
node.attr("data-count") = sum(node.children('li').attr("data-count"));
```

Can anyone help me fix this phrase?

Comment: you can try this `var count = 0;
$('li').each(function(){
    count += $(this).data('count');
});`

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt()`, otherwise `js` will parse the `var` as a `string`.

```js
  var sum = 0;
  $( "li" ).each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).attr( "data-count" ));
  });

  alert(sum) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-count="3">
  <li data-count="3">
    <li data-count="3">
      <li data-count="2">
      </li>
      <li data-count="1">
      </li>
    </li>
  </li>
</li>
```

Comment: each parent only has count total of it's children

Answer (score 1):

If you want a count from children:

```
var $parents = $('someSelector');
// loop over all parent elements needing counts
$parents.each(function () {       
    var $el = $(this),
        // get total of children `count`
        count = $el.children().get().reduce(function (total, child) {
            return total + $(child).data('count')
        }, 0);
    // set on element
    $el.data('count', count);
});
```

Using `data()` both reads `data-` attributes and sets value on element. When value is numeric it will be type cast to number internally